# Как получать содержимое тегов xml через XPath в IE

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        showResult(xhttp.responseXML);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "tovar.xml", true);
xhttp.send(); 

function showResult(xml) {
    var txt = "";

    if (xml.evaluate) {
       path = "/result/page/properties/group[1]/property[2]/value";
       var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
       var result = nodes.iterateNext();
       tpname=result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
       console.log(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);

    // Code For Internet Explorer
    } else {
        //} else if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        path = "/result/page/properties/group[1]/property[2]/value";
        xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");

    }

}
```

Ломается с ошибкой: Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "setProperty". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А какую версию IE используете?

Comment: 11.0.9600.18163